# continually importing data from many excel spreadsheets into one

Tags: excel, file, import

So I have never used Excel macros before, and am not experienced in this, but have a (very) rough idea of how things work. I have tried looking up solutions but too inexperienced to convert them to my situation.

I have to import data from many excel files into one main database, and have this going at the click of a button, as there are new files being generated daily.

I can set up the data files to have the values in a consistent format on the first sheet of the file, as a start. From there I am not sure of the coding I need to use to get the data imported to the database file and append it to the bottom of a list.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have been continuing my research and decided the best way forwards is going to be to have a button on each of the datafiles which will move the values onto the main spreadsheet. As the files are all over the place and continually used as the base for new versions, using the data spreadsheets as the open sheets and only having to have a pathway to one destination file should minimise effort. Still failing to actually do this though

Answer (score 0):

By "one main database" are you referring to an actual database (e.g. SQL Server) or an Excel file. If an excel file, I'd use PowerQuery for this. It's built into Excel 2016, available as a free add-in for Excel 2010/2013, and designed so that non-coders can do incredible data cleaning and prep work from a fairly easy-to-use UI built right into Excel. Plenty of tutorials on the web and youtube, as well as great books such as *M is for Data Monkeys* by Ken Puls.

Comment: I do mean an excel file for the main database, unfortunately - my work is a bit backwards.
I'm not sure that dataquery is the best way to approach this. I need to basically have a system in place so that low tech users can press a button once they are done working on a spreadsheet and the data exports to the main sheet.
I have found some coding which does everything I want, can't get it to work for me though - getting 
'runtime error '1004':
Application-defined or object-defined error"

trying to figure out why this is occuring

Comment: Powerquery will do that, and is a heck of a lot easier to learn than VBA. And yes, it refreshes painlessly just by right-clicking and selecting the Refresh option. What version of Excel do you and your users have?